# resizing image using pil while uploading in django

Tags: python, django

Checked many other answers and didn't find what am looking for! I'm working on a Django project and I have to let the user upload photos, now I need to resize the photos to fit the place where it will be shown at

here are my files :

**models**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # custom validators
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

    # fields
    dress_name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', null=False, verbose_name='وصف الفستان',)
    dress_size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='مقاس الفستان')
    dress_color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='لون الفستان')
    dress_image1 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=False, verbose_name='الصورة الأساسية للفستان',
                                     help_text='لا يمكنك تركها فارغة',)
    dress_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافية ')
    dress_image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, verbose_name='صورة إضافة ')
    dress_action = models.ForeignKey(Action, on_delete='DO_NOTHING', verbose_name='الفستان معروض لل ',
                                     help_text='للبيع او للإيجار ')
    dress_price = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='السعر')
    dress_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete='CASCADE', verbose_name='البلد')
    dress_city = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='المدينة او المحافظة')
    dress_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric], verbose_name='رقم الهاتف ')
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    created_username = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='unknown')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    dress_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dress_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms**

```
class AddDressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['created_by', 'created_at','dress_active','dress_special','created_username']

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image', False)
        if image:
            if image._size > 4*1024*1024:
                raise ValidationError("Image file too large ( > 4mb )")
            return image
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded image")
```

and finally **views**

```
def dress_add(request):
    all_name = Name.objects.all()
    current_user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        add_dress_form = AddDressForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if add_dress_form.is_valid():
            model_instance = add_dress_form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.created_by = current_user.first_name
            model_instance.created_username = current_user.username
            if model_instance.dress_image1:
                model_instance.dress_image1 = Image.open(model_instance.dress_image1)
                model_instance.dress_image1.resize((1000, 1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                thumb_io = BytesIO()
                model_instance.dress_image1.save(thumb_io, model_instance.format, quality=60 )
                model_instance.image.save(model_instance.filename, ContentFile(thumb_io.get_value()), save=False)
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('dress_confirm')

    else:
        add_dress_form = AddDressForm()

    context = {
        'add_dress_form':add_dress_form,
        'current_user':current_user,
        'all_name':all_name,

    }

    return render(request, 'fostan/dress_add.html', context)
```

I've tried to use the resize method in PIL lib to resize the image but it gives me an error

**error**

`'Item' object has no attribute 'format'

**partly Solved**

1 - changed `model_instance.dress_image1.save(thumb_io, model_instance.format, quality=60 )`

to be like :

`model_instance.dress_image1.save(thumb_io, model_instance.dress_image1.format, quality=60 )`

2 - then changed `model_instance.filename` to `model_instance.dress_image1.filename` 
`

3-then changed `model_instance.image.save(model_instance.filename, ContentFile(thumb_io.get_value()), save=False)`

to be `                model_instance.dress_image1.save(model_instance.dress_image1.filename, ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)

**error**

then now I have a new error which is

`'ContentFile' object has no attribute 'upper'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
model_instance.dress_image1.save(thumb_io, model_instance.format, quality=60 )
```

You probably want this:

```
model_instance.dress_image1.save(thumb_io, model_instance.dress_image1.format, quality=60 )
```

Comment: `'Item' object has no attribute 'filename'
` still returns an error !

Comment: @AhmedWagdi That was just the first hint. Same idea, `model_instance.filename` on the next line is wrong. Should be something like `model_instance.dress_image1.filename`

Comment: thank men It is the right steps because now I have an error in the last line  `'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'get_value'`